# Remove local stored emails from apple mail but keep on server

Tags: mail.app, email

Is it somehow possible to set up Mail that all emails stay on the server and are not fully downloaded to my mac?

I have a local mailaccount set up on our NAS as a backup for our emails. After some time I move all emails from the main account there.
The inbox is about 150GB right now and all of it is kept offline on the mac. Is it possible to remove that locally but keep it on the server? And only when accessing an email or attachment it gets downloaded?

I couldn't find such option.

I'm using IMAP for the backup mailbox, but if it's working with POP3 I can switch it.

Thanks!

Comment: I've been doing this with my gmail account for years. Mail.app is set to POP and to download all messages *and leave them on the server.* But I leave my iPhone/iPad and the web client alone in IMAP. It means a little more manually moving/deleting email but it works for me. It just depends on if that mail server supports both.

Comment: @SteveChambers Good idea. So you set it to POP and delete everything local? This way it will stay on the server but your drive is empty. But how would you access an old email when you need it? Don't you have to redownload everything then?

Comment: Actually I keep pretty much all email in both locations, but then have to manage (essentially) two inboxes as payment for using a POP email client as a backup. So it would depend on *your personal* needs/workflow but, yes, that would work. If I cant find an email locally I search in Gmail and just use the webmail interface.

Comment: I suppose the lion's share of those 150GB are attachments. You can configure Mail to not download attachments. The setting is under Preferences > Accounts > _Account name_. You can either choose to download all attachments , only recent attachments, or prevent attachments from being downloaded.

Comment: @jaume Thanks. I overlooked that. I have to delete the mailbox and add it again to actually do anything right? So attachments won't get deleted automatically if already downloaded?

Comment: @jona Good question, I would expect that changing the setting triggers some sort of internal job that deletes the attachments. Just set Download Attachments to None and then check after a couple of hours (the cleanup may need some time). If that doesn't work, you can either rebuild the mailboxes (which effectively forces Mail to download messages again) or remove the mail account and add it again.

Comment: @jaume You can add it as answer (I think). It solves my problem and reduces the local mailbox size dramatically but it's not 100% what the question is about. So not sure how to handle this here on stackexchange :)

Comment: @jona Fair enough, no worries. Let's see, maybe someone comes up in the near future with an answer that better fits your question (though I think the method I describe is the most flexible approach :-)